# Usage of key in max function and argument-less count method

Tags: python, list

```
list_x = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'E']
x = max(set(list_x), key=list_x.count)
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here? I know max() returns the max value and the set() would return set of the given list but what is `, key=list_x.count` there? (also, why there is no input for count method? ie. `list_x.count("B")` )

Note: I got this line from someone else's submission online.

Comment: See the documentation: [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: Also see the docs for `list.count`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) goes through the given iterable and returns the largest item.

The `key` parameter (also used in `list.sort()`, `min()`, and other similar functions) can be passed a function that's used to get what key to sort on.  Basically, this `key` function is called once for each item in the iterable and that value is used for sorting instead.

The `list_x.count` count method is a reference to [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).  This returns how many times the item is in the list.

Another way to write what you have would be:

```
max(set(list_x), key=lambda item: list_x.count(item))
```

It's just that instead of passing a function/`lambda` that calls `list_x.count()` to `key`, the `list_x.count` function itself was passed.

`set()` is being used here because a `set` can only contain unique elements.  Since you are getting the count for each element, it is faster to use a `set` so you are not calling `list_x.count('B')` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This computes the element in `list_x` that is repeated the most. `set(list_x)` is used to compute the `max` over, and for each (unique, of course) element in the set, the count of that element in the list is computed (as in `list_x.count('B')`, for example).
So:

```
list_x = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'E']
x = max(set(list_x), key=list_x.count)
# x = 'B'
list_x = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'A']
x = max(set(list_x), key=list_x.count)
# x = 'A'
```